# Error on my beginner project

Tags: python

I'm new to everything related to programming, and just finished an intro to python course and was trying to start a few projects.
I'm running into something I can't figure out.

```
lives=3
while lives>0:

  low=raw_input("what is the lower range that you will guess? Numbers only please.")
  high=raw_input("what is the higher range that you will guess? Numbers only please")
  thenumber=randint(int(low),int(high))
  if int(raw_input("pick an integer between %s and %s") %(low, high))==thenumber:
        print "you won!"
```

after setting both variables to "1", it prints "pick a integer between %s and %s" rather than "pick an integer between 1 and 1".

edit:after submitting a number for a guess, I also get

```
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

Comment: In general, try Googling any error you get: https://www.google.it/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=TypeError:+not+all+arguments+converted+during+string+formatting&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&gfe_rd=cr&dcr=0&ei=APa9Wc6ADq_CXuzysZgC

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check the parentheses:

```
raw_input("pick an integer between %s and %s") %(low, high) #bad

raw_input("pick an integer between %s and %s" % (low, high)) #good
```

Comment: Not only at the beginning. your future self will kick you in the rear for not commenting that one script properly... :)

Answer (score 2):

Your `%s` substitutions are outside the brackets that encase `raw_input`; they should immediately follow the string (as in kip's answer).

Just use the `.format` syntax. Much easier to understand in my opinion.

This:

```
"pick an integer between %s and %s" % (low, high)
```

Can be written as:

```
"pick an integer between {} and {}".format(low, high)
```

You could also do it Ruby style (in Python 3.5+):

```
f"pick an integer between {low} and {high}"
```